# Load chunks/bundles as needed (like SystemJS)

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

Using Webpack, I have multiple chunks/bundles being created so that the entire app is not loaded at once. I've hand-chosen which dependencies I want to be moved into their own chunks. Here is the important part of my config:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'runtime',
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        ...makeChunkCacheGroup('chunk_1', /\/node_modules\/(... list of deps ...)(\/|$)/),
        ...makeChunkCacheGroup('chunk_2', /\/node_modules\/(... list of deps ...)(\/|$)/),
      },
    },
  },
// ...
};

function makeChunkCacheGroup(name, ...moduleNameRegexps) {
  return {
    [name]: {
      name,
      test: module => moduleNameRegexps.some(pattern => pattern.test(module.context)),
      chunks: 'all',
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 0,
      maxSize: Infinity,
      reuseExistingChunk: true,
      enforce: true,
    },
  };
}
```

This config gives me `runtime`, `main`, `chunk_`, and `chunk_2`. However, all of these chunks are injected into `index.html`, thus they all load during the initial page load instead of dynamically (as I naively expected).

I've used SystemJS in the past to bundle things up into multiple bundles and it would only download a given bundle as it was required by the app. I now realize that Webpack does not work this way.

Is there a way to make Webpack only download the `runtime` and `main` bundles initially, and then download the other bundles as they're needed?

---

*Note 1:* I realize that I can use dynamic imports e.g. `import('some-dep').then(...)`, but it's not reasonable to do so based on the size of the codebase, and also, I think this sort of thing is better left to configuration (a module shouldn't have to pick and choose which deps it should load dynamically).

*Note 2:* I did try to specify multiple entry points but never got it working. The app really only has a single entry point. But, for instance, we have multiple directories under `src/app/elements/`, and it'd be perfect if each of those directories ended up in its own bundle which was then dynamically loaded. I couldn't get this working in an automated/smart way.

Comment: On note1, isn't it reasonable to expect the application knows the best for when to load a module? e.g. you can naturally write sth like `doSth() { const dep = await import('dep'); dep.runSth() };`

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't belong in "code". Especially the way I'd have to do it with Webpack, that is, using "magic comments" e.g. `import (/** webpackChunkName: chunk_1 */ /** webpackMode: lazt **/ 'my-dep');`

This is very hacky and brittle. Configuration does not belong in code, it belongs in config. /rant